# Calling a MySQL query from a shell script after some time interval

Tags: mysql, windows, bash, shell, mingw

I wanted to execute a MySQL query from a shell script after some time. I have written the script but the output is not as expected. It is printing the same value again from the database. Can someone please help.

**SCRIPT-** demo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Shell Script to Query a Database!"
echo "--Querying from the Database starts--"
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
for i in {1..5};
do 
./mysql -u root -proot@123 << EOF
use catalyst_latest;
select id from ci_master limit 1;
EOF
echo "Wait for 2 seconds for the next ID." 
sleep 2; 
done
echo "--Query Stopped!--"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ ./demo.sh
Shell Script to Query a Database!
--Querying from the Database starts--
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be   insecure.
id
282
Wait for 2 seconds for the next ID.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
id
282
Wait for 2 seconds for the next ID.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
id
282
Wait for 2 seconds for the next ID.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
id
282
Wait for 2 seconds for the next ID.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
id
282
Wait for 2 seconds for the next ID.
--Query Stopped!--
```

Can you see that 282 getting returned every time? So i want the next ID from the database after 2 seconds. Please tell me how to do it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember the returned `id` value into the bash variable and then reusing that variable in `WHERE` clause of the query like this:

```
select id from ci_master where id > $id limit 1
```

To write output of the command into variable use something like this:

```
id=$(mysql <options> -Nsqe "<query>")
```

Option `N` to skip column names (like id), option `s` for more silent output, option `q` for not caching result, option `e` for the command to execute.

Initially the `$id` variable should be set to some value like 1 or the minimum of existing values in the table.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander. I did something like this -

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Shell Script to Query a Database!"
echo "--Querying from the Database starts--"
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
for i in {1..10};
do 
temp=`./mysql -u root -proot@123 << EOF
use catalyst_latest;
select id from ci_master limit $i;
EOF`
result=''
for j in $temp 
do 
result=$j
done
#date;
echo "$result"
echo "Wait for 1 seconds for the next ID." 
sleep 1; 
done
echo "--Query Stopped!--"
```